# Why do we sometimes use nouns without articles?

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives, articles

Why is the adjective "nonsensical" not used in the following sentence? And why is the noun form correct? Why do we never use an article before the word "nonsense"? Isn't it a noun? has it something to do with the fact that it's uncountable?

> "The translation of the instructions was so poor they were just nonsense."

Or

> "The story he told us was nonsense."

What about the word "luxury"? What is the difference between "a luxurious car" and "a luxury car"? I believe the latter one is more common for some reason I can't find. I mean "luxury" is a noun, why do we use it to modify another noun when we can use the adjectival form "luxurious"?

I hope I was able to convey what I mean well enough.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: People are continually reinventing nouns as adjectives where appropriate ones already exist. Others copy them because they sound new, different or trendy. Hadn't you noticed?

Comment: _Nonsense_ can be defined as _words that make no sense_, so it's perfectly reasonable to say that a story etc. is nonsense (without an article).

Comment: English is often illogical, idiosyncratic. For instance, why do almost all of us agree to capitalise I but not you?

Comment: English frequently allows nouns to be used as verbs, verbs to be used as nouns, nouns to be used as adjectives, etc.

Comment: @Barmar ***Any*** verb (except for defective ones, mainly modals because they lack the necessary  infinitives and participles for it) can always be used as a noun or adjective. *Driving in the driven snow drove me crazy.*

Comment: @tchrist True, that's the basic function of a gerund. But I was thinking of things like "I'm sending you an invite."

Comment: Either is fine. It's the same as asking why we say *car* instead of *automobile*. (But we say both, and it's a matter of personal choice.)